# getting bound Selectable from ORM query

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use [pandas-sqlalchemy-pivot](https://github.com/tomasd/pandas-sqlalchemy-pivot) to create pivot tables based on SQLAlchemy ORM query results.

The functions of this module (e.g. `pivots.pivot_table_from_select`) are designed to work with SQLAlchemy [core selectables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html), rather than with ORM queries.

I figured I could use the [Query.selectable](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.selectable) attribute to convert the ORM query to a core selectable object, but this gives an error:

```
>>> q=session.query( ... )
>>> df = pivots.pivot_table_from_select(q.selectable(), rows="field", cols="state", values="count")
  File "...\site-packages\pivots\table.py", line 25, in pivot_table_from_select
    data = pivot_data(select, rows, cols, values)
  File "...\site-packages\pivots\table.py", line 74, in pivot_data
    data = pivot_select.execute(bind=select.bind).fetchall()
  File "...\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 385, in execute
    raise exc.UnboundExecutionError(msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: This Select object is not directly bound to a Connection or Engine.Use the .execute() method of a Connection
Engine to execute this construct.
```

I can't figure out why this object is unbound, since the original `Query` object is certainly bound to a specific session and engine.

I get the same error if I try to execute the query, even with an explicit bind:

```
>>> q.selectable.execute(bind=engine)
```

... but if I do this instead, it works:

```
>>> engine.execute(q.selectable)
```

I'd like to be able to use the unmodified `pandas-sqlalchemy-pivot` module; is there a way to get a bound selectable from the query object which I'm overlooking?

Comment: I'm not seeing why bound selectables are needed here, and I generally don't recommend them.   If you have a SQL construct and you want to execute it, it's best that your program has an explicit notion of where it is getting connectivity from and what transaction it is running within.  Why not have a Connection present for the scope of which you work with the database?

Comment: @zzzeek, I was hoping to be able to execute the query in the default context of the `session` object, without managing an explicit `Connection` scope.

Comment: then execute with the Session:  `session.execute(q.selectable)`

Comment: Certainly, I can do that. It's just that the aforementioned module assumes a bound selectable, and I was surprised that `Query.selectable` does not meet that definition; perhaps it's because a `session` does not necessarily map 1:1 to a `Connection`.